# Laravel Routing issue when using POST Method

Tags: laravel, methods, routes, laravel-routing

I am trying to call controller using Routes. Everything is working fine when using GET method. When I worked on Post, i am not able to call the controller. Please check the below.

Error Code: Routing is not working

```
 Route::post('/accountSignUp', [
'as' => 'accountSignUp',
'uses' => 'UsersController@accountSignUp'
 ]);
```

can anybody suggest how to do it.

I checked in log.. Getting the below error message..

```
[2014-11-07 13:30:46] dev.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /var/www/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:148
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1049): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /var/www/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1017): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /var/www/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /var/www/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /var/www/project_name/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/Stack.php(34): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 /var/www/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\Stack->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 /var/www/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /var/www/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /var/www/project_name/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#10 /var/www/project_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /var/www/project_name/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#12 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have defined your routes this way:

```
Route::method(['POST', 'GET'], '/accountSignUp', [
 'as' => 'accountSignUp',
'uses' => 'UsersController@accountSignUp'
 ]);
```

Now in your controller to get any values you can simply use `echo Input::get('username')` - you use `get` method both for POST and GET data.

Comment: @Kishore Show your form

Comment: Basically I am working for API development. So, i am using  Postman. Anyway, I got the result by using "any" instead of "post". thank you..

Comment: @Kishore So you used other method that you wrote in your question - probably PUT/PATCH/DELETE